# Python regex How to check with NOT condition for group backreference OR ignoring a group item in backreference

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group, backreference

Problem:- A number is valid if the alternate numbers are different. In case if the alternate numbers are same and the in-between number is also same then they are valid again

```
example:-
123456 :- This number is valid as we don't have any alternate number as same, all are different
110100:- This number is invalid as in  010  alternate numbers are same and in-between is different
110000 :- this number is valid as in 000 alternate number though are same in-between is also same
```

What I tried

```
import re
st="1101010"
#st="110000"
re.findall(r"(\d)[^\1]&[\d]\1", st)
```

I was trying to not the group item by back referencing and using an AND condition, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Your regex reads as follows: "Match a digit (cap grp 1) followed by a character other than `1` followed by `&`, followed by a digit followed by the content of cap grp 1." You cannot have a back-reference in a character class (search for *Parentheses and Backreferences Cannot Be Used Inside Character Classes* [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). `&` is treated as a literal character. `[\d]` is OK but is the same as `\d`. The alternative to having a negated back-reference in a character class is to use a negative lookahead.

Comment: Thank You very much this was really helpful

Comment: I simplified my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression

```
r"(\d)(?!\1)\d\1"
```

Strings that match this regex contain a string `aba` where `a` is any character and `b` is any character other than `a`.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0zA1q/3/)

[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/96ffwcin)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(\d)    # match a digit and save to cap grp 1
(?!\1)  # the next char cannot be the content of cap grp 1
\d      # match a digit
\1      # match the content of cap grp 1
```

Comment: Thank You Cary., it worked for me. Could you help me find out why my initial solution didnt work , this is just for knowledge.

Comment: As you will see I did that in a comment on the question.